# inserting elements in an array based on values from another array

Tags: arrays, vba

I have two very large files that need information passed between them. Currently I am looping through the larger of the two files and using an array to store the smaller file. I then update the fields in the larger file with elements from the array and this works but it takes a long time to loop through the file. What I am trying to do is have both files in separate arrays and loop through the arrays and insert the elements from one array into the other much like I do with the files.

I can find what I'm looking for I am having a hard time inserting the name.

```
'loop through first Array
For X = UBound(arrOne) To 2 Step -1

    'loop through second array
    For A = UBound(arrTwo) To LBound(arrTwo) Step -1

        'check if the primary key in the first array is in the second array
        If arrOne(X, 1) = arrTwo(A, 1) Then

            'if the keys match find the secondary key 
            'AND make sure the name field is empty
            If arrOne(X, 69) = arrTwo(A, 2) And arrOne(X, 83) = "" Then

               'if keys match and there is no name - insert the name 
               'from arrTwo into arrOne
                arrOne.Add(X, 69) arrTwo(A, 2)

            End If

        Else

            'Insert Empty Values into Insurance rows

        End If
    Next A
Next A
```

Comment: What format are the files? CSV? Simple lines of text?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays do not have an `Add` method.  If you just want to assign a value from one array to a slot in the other:

```
 arrOne(X, 69) = arrTwo(A, 2)
```

It's unclear what the purpose of that line is though, since you already checked those two values were equal?

If you only expect a single match then adding `Exit For` after that line will speed up your processing.